# Could'nt connect in PDO to mysql database, using apache with easyPHP on port 8080

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo

I'm using EasyPHP on my localhost:8080, and IIS7.5 on my localhost:80.
Work like a charm.

I can access phpmyadmin with no problem at this address :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/modules/phpmyadminXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
```

Using root and no password.

---

My question is, why is my connection doesn't work at all. No response, no error message, nothing. The page continue to load forever...
There is my code:

```
<?php
$db_server              = '127.0.0.1:8080';                 // DB Server Address
$db_user                = 'root';                   // DB Username
$db_pass                = '';                   // DB Password
$db_database            = 'my_dbnameXXXX';              // Database Name
try{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_server.'; dbname='.$db_database,$db_user, $db_pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT,3600);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Yes i try with localhost:8080, doesn't work either...

Can some one help me? Thanks. I'll stay around to response to comments or questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL usually listens on port 3306, not 8080 which is the port your webserver is listening to.

Comment: So, one can just not specify a port and it will use the default, which is likely correct here.

Comment: Then your database is probably listening on a different port and you need to figure that out.

Comment: Oh well, after I restart the apache and the mysql server; it works ! Thanks alot sebotron.

Answer (score 0):

You should be specifying `host=` and `port=` separately. I don't think PDO supports the colon-style notation you're using there.

Also note that MySQL is port 3306 by default, but 8080 is for your web server. Try not to confuse the two.